# React Native white background output on Listview

Tags: android, mobile, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm making a list view were I will view a list of some data from my database. But after running the program all I got is white background screen. Does anyone knows the solution?

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1Rvu.png)

Here is my code

```
export default class Pasta extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            dataSource: []
        }
    }

    renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
            <View style = {{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <View style = {{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <Text>
                        {item.menu_desc}
                    </Text>
                    <Text>
                        {item.menu_price}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
    )
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const url = 'http://192.***.***.***:9090/menu'

        fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({
                dataSource: responseJson.menu
            })
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style = { styles.container }>
                <FlatList
                    data = { this.state.dataSource }
                    renderItem = {this.renderItem}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: add `console.log(this.state.dataSource)` to right after `render() {` and add the output

Comment: Have you given uniqe keys for the renderItems which will be called in FlatList. Could you please show the code for FlatList

Comment: @stack26, that's all is my code sir. I think i use "renderItem" to call it in the Flatlist and renderItem contains "item" which will be use to display the data from my db to Text.

Answer (score 0):

Add `extraData` prop to your `FlatList` to cause a re-render

```
keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id; // note: id is the unique key for each item

render() {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data = {this.state.dataSource}
      renderItem = {this.renderItem}
      extraData={this.state}
      keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
    />
   );
  }
```

Also log and verify your data is present. I suggest referring to [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) docs for more props like `keyExtractor` etc.

Comment: Didn't work sir, and now i have warning saying;
TypeError: Network request failed

Comment: let's debug, replace your url with http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts and verify if you're able to get a response.

Comment: sir, there's no changes. I still have the white background, and even if i set a backgroundcolor: "black" it wouldn't change.

Comment: No problem..do you get responseJson inside .then((responseJson) => { console.log(responseJson); this.setState({ dataSource: responseJson}) }). Also log this.state.dataSource inside the render function.

Comment: I did the console.log(responseJson); before this.setState, sir. And now, in the developer tool in my browser all the data in your link has been displayed. But I don't get you point about "log this.state.dataSource inside the render function" what do you mean in this part?

Comment: Inside the render() { console.log(this.state.dataSource); //.. } to verify. You also need to change your renderItem function to use <Text> {item.title} </Text> or a static text.

Comment: This medium article by spencer is helpful to get started https://medium.com/react-native-development/how-to-use-the-flatlist-component-react-native-basics-92c482816fe6.

Comment: Hello sir, I just manage to display some list of names just now, but I have another warning saying; VirtualizedList: missing keys for items, make sure to specify a key property on each item or provide a custom keyExtractor.

Comment: Use the keyExtractor method from above answer. Use item.id if present or any other key which is unique across each list element.